# How do you load data to DynamoDB from Xcode using Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, amazon-dynamodb

I am a fairly new developer, and right now I am developing an app where I am using the DynamoDB database to collect user account info, then acquire it to verify during a login. However, I'm having trouble because all the instructions detailing how to deploy data to DynamoDB are written for iOS developers using Objective-C. I do not know Objective-C and am having a hard time trying to figure out what it means. Also, for those familiar with DynamoDB, do I have to use Amazon Cognito when uploading to DynamoDB?

Answer (score 0):

The DynamoDB Object Mapper is a ORM layer that lets you use DynamoDB as a back-end for storing your data.

It seems like [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/DynamoDBObjectMapper-Sample/Swift) is an example of how to use DynamoDB mapper with swift.